# does "simpering" implies a bad quality in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, implication

does "simpering" implies a bad quality in this context?

> John Page Hopps describes her at this time as "a small, thin, very
>   intelligent, but rather **simpering** little woman, with nice, gentle
>   manners and a quiet enjoyment of her experiments which entirely saved
>   her from the slightest touch of self-importance or affectation of
>   mystery."

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: To describe someone's smile as a simper is not usually very complimentary, but he goes on to say quite favourable things about her, so your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: To [**simper**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/simper) is usually a harmless action, although not very becoming.

Comment: To call someone 'simpering' is **always** insulting.

Comment: @Michael Harvey  but the whole text doesn't imply such a thing.

Comment: @Michael Harvey why conan doyle texts are ambiguous like this? lol

Comment: "very intelligent **but** rather simpering"... why do you think that 'but' is there? I tell you. To call someone simpering is negative. It is never good to be called "affectedly coy or ingratiating.".

Comment: They are not really ambiguous.

Comment: @Michael Harvey omg. you are right dear michael. i did not notice "but rather". thanks for your help. i must read the text carefully.

Comment: It's just the 'but' you should notice; 'rather' modifies 'simpering'.

Answer (score 1):

To simper is to 'to smile in a silly or annoying way'; some dictionaries say 'smile in a silly, affected, or ingratiating manner'. To state that someone does these things is to say a negative thing about them.

[Simper (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simper)
[Simper (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simper)